# sort by multiple conditions using uasort() php

Tags: php, sorting

I have array of json objects and I want to sort it ascending and also put the null values in the end. following is the code I tried. Both uasort() is working perfectly fine individually but When I put them one after another, it just sort the array based on the latest function.

How can I sort the array in ascending order and also put null values at the end of that ascending sorted list?

```php
uasort($arr, function($a,$b) { 
        return $a->score > $b->score ? 1 : -1; 
    });

uasort($arr, function($a) {
     return ( is_null($a->score==NULL) OR $a->score == "") ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Comment: `is_null($a->score==NULL)` should just be `is_null($a->score)`

Comment: Only one function, in case the main criteria are equal, sort for the second criteria (same procedure for more sort criterias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one comparison function that tests both conditions.

```
uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a->score === $b->score) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ($a->score === NULL || $a->score === "") {
        return 1;
    }
    if ($b->score === NULL || $b->score === "") {
        return -1;
    }
    return $a->score > $b->score ? 1 : -1; 
}
```

Comment: This code put null values on top, I want null at the bottom of the list.

Comment: Then just swap `-1` and `1`.

Comment: swapping -1  to 1 put score's on descending order. I want score on ascending order and put null at the bottom.

Comment: I meant just swap them in the part that checks for `NULL`. I made that change when I posted the comment.

Comment: Yeah, I did that too but still null is on the top.

Comment: I made a mistake putting all the null checks inside the test that both scores are equal.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but its not working.  Tried this with demo array as well and still null comes at the top. `$arr=['a',null,'b','    ','c','d'];
uasort($arr, function($a, $b) {
        if ($a === $b)
        {
            return 0;
        }
            
        if ($a === NULL || $a === "")
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if ($b === NULL || $b === "")
        {
            return 1;
        }
        
        return $a > $b ? 1 : -1;
    });
print_r($arr);`

Comment: I had the signs right originally, the problem was just the `===` test around it. I just tested the above code, it works.

Comment: Note that the 4th element of your test array is not an empty string, it contains a space, so it won't match the `=== ""` conditions.

Comment: You might want to use `trim($b->score) === ""` to ignore surrounding whitespace.

Comment: Sorry. my bad, forgot about trimming. it works now! Thank you so much for your help!!